# Resizing an EC2 instance using boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am writing a Python 2.7 script that will stop an EC2 instance, resize the instance, then start the instance back up. Is there a way to use boto3 to resize an instance? If not, is there another way to handle instance resizing programmatically?

Comment: Go through this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907783/how-to-change-aws-ec2-instance-type

Comment: By resize, do you mean change the instance type or change the EBS volume size?

Comment: @KarenB I should have clarified, I meant changing the instance type.

Comment: @error2007s I had already seen that post, which I guess I should have mentioned in my post. It is not helpful, however: the code in the question is pseudocode and the answer is about the general process of changing an instance type and has nothing to do with boto3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

# Insert your Instance ID here
my_instance = 'i-xxxxxxxx'

# Stop the instance
client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[my_instance])

# Change the instance type
client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')

# Start the instance
client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
```

Comment: What is waiter representing here. I am also new to aws buto3 and trying to resize the instance and the type

Comment: @user3713336 From [`Waiter.InstanceStopped` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStopped): _Polls `EC2.Client.describe_instances()` every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks._