# How can I do AWS EC2 instance auto scale down in night (stop & change to t2.small) and automatic scale up (stop & go to t2.large) in morning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, instance, aws-auto-scaling

I am looking `AWS EC2` autoscaling feature that can automatically stop my EC2 instance at night and change my instance type (i.e: **t2.xlarge** to **t2.small**) for the whole night and in the morning again stop EC2 instance and change instance type (i.e **t2.small** to **t2.xlarge**) on daily basis.

***Please note:***
I have already checked with **IAM** role > created role to grant permission for changes. & created **Lambda** function and insert code for stop and restart the instance with the help of `AWS CloudWatch`  but I need code which can stop instance and then change type in a specific time for night and morning.

Comment: Auto Scaling groups are designed to 'scale-out' by _adding_ instances and 'scale-in' by _removing_ instances. It is _not_ designed to change the instance type. You should scale by changing the **quantity** of instances rather than their **size**. Also, be very careful when using T-family instances with Auto Scaling groups -- if you have a Scaling Policy based on CPU Utilization, it will not work because T-family instances have limits in their CPU and they will never actually go to 100% for long periods.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule `CloudWatch` events, that call `AWS lambda` functions.
In the function you can change the instance type with AWS SDK [ModifyInstanceAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyInstanceAttribute.html) API.

See below an example with `boto3`:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
# ....
client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')
```

> See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38671007/8718377

Comment: The instance needs to be Stopped before the instance type can change. If the instance was launched by Auto Scaling, then the Auto Scaling group will probably Terminate the instance since it isn't running. So, this approach probably isn't a good idea for Auto Scaling groups.

Comment: Timely I am trying to auto stop and start but my code shows an error while testing it "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds " Do you have any idea how to fit it?